# WSL - /dev/loop0 workaround

Tags: mount, devices, windows-subsystem-for-linux, loop-device

I am trying to setup Bochs as shown in [this tutorial](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/1.-Environment%20setup.html). However, I'm using WSL and there is no loop0 device.

```
# bochsrc.txt #
megs:        32
romimage:    file=/usr/share/bochs/BIOS-bochs-latest, address=0xf0000
vgaromimage: /usr/share/bochs/VGABIOS-elpin-2.40
floppya:     1_44=/dev/loop0, status=inserted
boot:        a
log:         bochsout.txt
mouse:       enabled=0
clock:       sync=realtime
cpu:         ips=500000

# update_image.sh #    
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 floppy.img
sudo mount   /dev/loop0 /mnt
sudo cp      src/kernel /mnt/kernel
sudo umount  /dev/loop0
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0 

# run_bochs.sh #
# mounts the correct loopback device, runs bochs, then unmounts
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 floppy.img
sudo bochs   -f bochsrc.txt
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Available devices are:

- block
- fd
- kmsg
- lxss
- null
- ptmx
- pts
- stdin
- stdout
- stderr
- shm
- tty[x]
- zero

Is there any way I can tweak the above code to work with an available device?

Answer (score 6):

There is no `/dev/` support in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). There is a [Microsoft User Voice Page](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/13818042-support-mounting-xfs-ext2-ext3-ext4-etc-partition) where you can comment your needs for such support. Currently 779 people have voted for this feature. You can post a comment linking back to this question and pointing out how the feature is needed to install your software.

For myself it would be great to have `/sys/class/backlight` support. It seems every WSL user has something they'd like supported in future versions.

Comment: Is there any feedback whatsoever from MS on this (and the FUSE) issue? I would like to know the roadmap...